# Область видимости переменной JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему переменная не видна за пределами функции?

**Например:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    test_ = $(window).width();
});
console.log(test_);
```

И можно ли ее получить вне функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если упростить, то в данном случае область видимости переменно ограничивается анонимной функцией. Это локальная переменная, которая не должна попасть за пределы функции (иначе в сложном проекте можно было бы что то перезаписать).

Чтобы получить значение вне функции нужно переменную `test_` объявить в самом начале, например так:

```
var test_;
$(document).ready(function(){
test_ = $(window).width();
});
console.log(test_);
```

Comment: И этот код, и код в вопросе выведут одно и то же - `undefined`.

Comment: @Yaant, it depends :)

Comment: @Grundy, а в каком случае будет что-то иное (если не предполагать, что `test_` присваивается какое-то значение где-то ещё в непоказанном нам коде)?

Comment: @Yaant, если событие DOMContentLoaded уже произошло, то коллбэк переданный в ready выполнится сразу.

Comment: @Grundy Хм, вообще сразу, а не на ближайшем тике event loop'а? Не знал, имхо, это несколько контринтуитивно, если так.

Comment: Я в самом деле ответил неточно, предполагая, что console.log(test_); вводится в консоли или вызывается где-то дальше в коде, который вызывается уже после полной загрузки документа. @mepihindeveloper, спасибо за уточнение

Comment: @Yaant, вообще, всегда казалось что да, но сейчас пересмотрел исходники там на их реализации Promise сделано

Answer (score 3):

В уточнение к @Stalker. `$(document).ready(function(){})` срабатывает только когда DOM отрисован, а `console.log(test_);` сразу как скрипт подгрузился.

Необходимо предварительно объявить через `var` переменную, чтобы так можно было обращаться. Но выдаст `undefined` по той причине, что я описал выше.

В твоем случае так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let test_ = $(window).width();
    console.log(test_);
});
```

Comment: записывайте в переменную глобальной области видимости window.
`$(document).ready(function(){
window.test_ = $(window).width();
});`

Comment: @EVG дельное предложение. Можно и так, все зависит от задачи.